# creating multiple rows based on record in an array - laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have the following query that brings back an array of user_ids, where each user will get notified.

```
$pstusrmembs = DB::table('postusrs')
                    ->where('post_id', $post_id)
                    ->where('accepted', 1)
                    ->pluck('user_id');
```

I need to put each user_id in a different row in the below "insert" code :

```
                      $notifs = new Notif();
                      $notifs->rec_uid = $pstusrmembs;
                      $notifs->title = $post_title;
                      $notifs->save();
```

How can I change `$notifs->rec_uid = $pstusrmembs;` to do this ?

Comment: so you want to store an array of ids in the `rec_uid` column?

Comment: json encode the array data and save data

Comment: @TharakaDilshan, I need to put each id in a row (not an array of ids in one column), where each row will have the same $post_title.

Comment: @AbdallahSakre Use For loop, I have added answer have a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use for loop for this:

```
foreach($pstusrmembs as $userID){
        $notifs = new Notif();
        $notifs->rec_uid = $userID;
        $notifs->title = $post_title;
        $notifs->save();
}
```

> And If You are using the Mass Assignment concept

```
foreach ($pstusrmembs as $userID) {
    Notif::create(['rec_uid' => $userID, 'title' => $post_title]);
  }
```

> And If You are using the Mass Assignment concept **Without Any Model
>   Events or Listeners**

```
foreach ($pstusrmembs as $userID) {
     $arrayOfNotif[] = ['rec_uid' => $userID, 'title' => $post_title];
  }

  Notif::insert($arrayOfNotif);
```

Answer (score 0):

I will recommend to use DB transaction to keep a database consistent even in cases of system failure and prepare that list as array and insert in one line ....

```
$prepare = [];
foreach($pstusrmembs as $p) {
  $prepare[] = [
    'rec_id' => $p,
    'title' => $post_title
  ];
}
DB::beginTransaction();
try {
   Notif::insert($prepare);
   DB::commit();
} catch (Exception $e) {
   DB::rollback();
}
```